# gaussian elimination to solve a question (using a paramter)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, solution-verification, gaussian-elimination

I want to solve :

```
    x2+x3=0
-x1   -x3=0
 x1-x2   =0
```

I got the $x_1 = -t,       x_2=-t,       x_3=t$.    But the book has  $x_1 = t,       x2=t,       x3=-t$.
Why don't we have the same answer? When I do Gaussian elimination I got this:

```
    x2+x3=0
 x1-x2   =0
```

Please help!

Comment: They are the same. Since t is any number, you can multiply all components by $-1$ to get the answer by the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is your system of linear equations:
$$
\begin{array}{lcl} x_1-x_2 &= 0\\ -x_1-x_3&=0\\ x_2+x_3&=0\end{array}
$$
Represent this system as an augmented matrix and perform the Guassian elimination:
$$\small
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\-1&0&-1&0\\0&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\0&-1&-1&0\\0&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\-1&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, we may represent the general solution as
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 &= -x_3\\
x_2 &= -x_3\\
x_3 & \text{is free.}
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$
If we let $x_3=t$, then $x_1=-t$ and $x_2=-t$, confirming *your* solution. However, if we let $x_3=-t$, then $x_1=t$ and $x_2 = t$, confirming the book's solution. You could come up with any sort of parameter you want to express $x_3$, but you will need to solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $(1)$ accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You do have the same answer.

$t$ is a parameter; it simply states that given any $t$ in $\mathbb R$, if you give those values to $x_1, x_2, x_3$ you will find solution to your problem.

Since $t$ can be anything, you may as well change sign to $t$ and find the same solution of your book.

But $t$ in itself is not important, what is important is the relationship that $t$ introduces on the solutions (that is, $x_1, x_2, x_3$). And the relationship that both you and your book find is that $x_1 = x_2 = -x_3$.

It is more convenient though to introduce an independent variable $t$. Look up [parametrization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization)

Comment: It is a little odd though that the book chose to let $x_3=-t$ don't you think? I'd imagine this would trip up students more than help them. At least they didn't let $x_3=-t+1-(\eta+\delta)$ or something truly absurd. Seems kind of weird.

Comment: @crash Maybe they wanted to point out this fact so students wouldn't panic when they encounter it during more complicated stuff :)

Comment: I suppose so (hopefully they added a note, but I imagine they didn't due to OP's confusion). Regardless, both of our answers (and comments) should clear up *any* confusion, and it seems OP found your answer to work satisfactorily. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and i got an answer same as the book,

```
-x2   -x3=0
 x1-x2   =0
```

We let x3=-t  then we get x1=x2=t